# Code coverage not including properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 for which I am writing unit tests using the unit testing framework.  When I view the code coverage results for a test run, the coverage does not include properties.  It doesn't show the properties as being either tested or non-tested, as if they aren't important at all.  Is there a setting I need to flip to turn on code coverage for properties?

Also note that I have already checked the .testsettings file and nothing is set to be excluded from code coverage, nor have I added any attributes to the classes/properties that would exclude them from coverage.

Comment: Do you have any logic within these properties that can be tested?

Comment: @ChrisBint That seems irrelevant. Even if the properties don't have any logic today (\*), they might tomorrow - and if you want to achieve 100% coverage, covering properties is a must. (\*) Actually, retrieving/setting data *is* logic.

Comment: @dcastro that would depend on the property implementation then. I do not believe auto properties have logic as such, at least not written in the same sense as a standard property. My point is that perhaps they are skipped entirely if there is no logic.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Properties do not appear to get added to Code Coverage, so I would check the implementation of your own properties.

For example, the following code produces 100% code coverage;

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var test = new Class1();
    Assert.IsNotNull(test);
}
```

Whereas the same test with the following changes to the Class give 40% coverage;

```
 public class Class1
    {
        private int _property1;

        public int Property1
        {
            get { return _property1; } 
            set { _property1 = value; }
        }
    }
```